# What is in Sheldon's room on his wall?

Tags: the-big-bang-theory

Season 1, episode 15: Leonard tries to talk to Sheldon to persuade him that he is a suitable mate for Sheldon's sister. The scene is taken in Sheldon's room.

[image: what is that object behind Sheldon?]

What is that object on the wall over Sheldon's right shoulder? It looks like it moves and there could be some sort of connector? Is it mechanical or electric perhaps?